# android syntax error while create table db

Tags: android, database, sqlite

my logcat message:

(1) near "INTEGER" : syntax error
Exception in CREATE_SQL
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "INTEGER" : syntax error (codee1): , while compiling: create BOMUL_PLACE( _id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOICREMENT, NAME TEXT, LAT DOUBLE, LNG DOUBLE, CHECK INTEGER DEFAULT 0);

and my code :

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            //TABLE_BOMUL_PLACE
           println("creating table [" + TABLE_BOMUL_PLACE + "].");

```
       //drop existing table
       String DROP_SQL = "drop table if exists " + TABLE_BOMUL_PLACE;
       try
       {
           db.execSQL(DROP_SQL);
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           Log.e(TAG, "Exception in DROP_SQL", ex);
       }


       String CREATE_SQL = "create table " +  TABLE_BOMUL_PLACE + "("
               + "  _id INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
               + "  NAME TEXT, "
               + "  LAT DOUBLE, "
               + "  LNG DOUBLE, "
               + "  CHECK INTEGER DEFAULT 0);";

       try 
       {
           db.execSQL(CREATE_SQL);
       } 
       catch(Exception ex) 
       {
           Log.e(TAG, "Exception in CREATE_SQL", ex);
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is from the `CHECK` column. `CHECK` is an SQL reserved word and needs to be renamed or `"quoted"`.

Other syntax problems from the logcat that you seem to have resolved in the code:

```
create BOMUL_PLACE( _id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOICREMENT, NAME TEXT, LAT DOUBLE, LNG DOUBLE, CHECK INTEGER DEFAULT 0
```

- `CREATE TABLE`, `TABLE` missing
- `AUTOINCREMENT` misspelled
- `)` missing at the end

Also, `NOT NULL` is redundant for a primary key column.

After fixing the `onCreate()`, uninstall your app so the previous database file gets deleted and `onCreate()` is called again. Catching exceptions is not recommended as `SQLiteOpenHelper`  will think that the creation succeeded if `onCreate()` returns normally.

Comment: thanks laalto your advice worked. "check" was problem

Answer (score -1):

You can try to add space between table name `TABLE_BOMUL_PLACE` and `(` symbol.

```
it should be 
TABLE_BOMUL_PLACE + " ("
```

Comment: try to rename column name `check`. It is keyword in SQLIte.